# How to change value of character_set_results variable to utfmb4 in MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql-8.0, utf8mb4

I am trying to read in a browser, the utf8 characters from MySQL database. After necessary changes made in my PHP code, I decided to edit *my.ini* in **MySQL 8.0** in my **Windows 11** machine.
Some changes made in my.ini does not reflect in the command line(providing screenshots below).
[image]

How to change these system variables to utf8mb4 (specially *character_set_results*)?

[image]